# Get IP input from user and validate WINAPI

Tags: c, winapi, ip

How can I get the IP that a user inserts in a IP Control box in Winapi, in a way that I can validate it after?

Already tried GetDlgItem() but it doesn't seem to store the IP in the correct format, maybe I'm doing it wrong. I was storing it as a DWORD.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You retrieve the IP address from an [IP Address Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761374.aspx) by sending an [IPM_GETADDRESS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761378.aspx) message<sup>1)</sup>:

```
DWORD dwAddr = 0x0;
SendMessage(hWndIpAddr, IPM_GETADDRESS, 0, (LPARAM)&dwAddr);
```

On return, the `DWORD` contains the IP address, where the MSB stores the first octet, while the LSB stores the 4th octet. You could output the address in human-readable format like this:

```
printf("%u.%u.%u.%u\n", (dwAddr >> 24) & 0xff,
                        (dwAddr >> 16) & 0xff,
                        (dwAddr >>  8) & 0xff,
                        (dwAddr      ) & 0xff);
```

Alternatively, use the [FIRST_IPADDRESS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761383.aspx), [SECOND_IPADDRESS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761387.aspx), [THIRD_IPADDRESS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761388.aspx), and [FOURTH_IPADDRESS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761384.aspx) macros to extract the address information:

```
printf("%u.%u.%u.%u\n", FIRST_IPADDRESS(dwAddr), SECOND_IPADDRESS(dwAddr),
                        THIRD_IPADDRESS(dwAddr), FOURTH_IPADDRESS(dwAddr));
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> *Since the address is returned in packed form as a `DWORD`, there is no need to validate it, since any `DWORD` (if interpreted as the 4 parts of an IPv4 address) is a valid address.*

Comment: There are macros for extracting the individual components from the `DWORD`: `FIRST_IPADDRESS()`, `SECOND_IPADDRESS()`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed by IInspectable one way is sending [IPM_GETADDRESS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, but second and simplest way is calling [GetWindowText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This remove unecessary printf.

```
WCHAR wAddress[64] = {0};
GetWindowTextW(hWndIpAddr, wAddress, 32);
```

Comment: I used `printf` to illustrate, how to extract the individual pieces of information from the `DWORD`. It's not needed. Now if you retrieve the textual representation, you will have to parse out the tokens to store it into a [sockaddr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740496.aspx), for example. And that really is the common use-case.